# IP adress for TCP-Socket to virtual machine

Tags: python, c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I want to set up socket-communication between my windows-pc and a linux virtual-machine. The windows-machine is the server. Ive written a C++-program that sets up the server on the winpc and a Python-program that sets up the client on the VM, but how do I connect them? Im using `SOCK_STREAM` and `AF_INET`, so I need a portnr and the ip-address to connect to the server. I was simply wondering what IP-adresse I should use, because it did not work with the IPv4, is this because its the wrong IP-adresse or because of errors in my program?

EDIT 1: Sorry for the unsufficient data:

I use Oracle Virtual Box, its networkconfig is set to default, NAT. When I run ipconfig in host (windows) cmd. I get out multiple IP-addresses:

> ```
> Windows IP Configuration
>
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : *
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : *
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ********
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : *
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : *
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : *
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : *
>
> **Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :*
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : *
>    Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : *
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : '*
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :***
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{*}:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ********
>    IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : *
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{5289AB9F-2C9F-4CBE-B826-149B3CFBB45F}:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :*
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.******:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : *******
>
> Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
>
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :*
> ```

I would be inclined to conclude that the IPv6-address under "Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network" would be the right one. I have tried pinging both the LAN-address and the VirtualBox host-only network-address, and they both yield results. I have also tried tracerout in terminal but that didnt work on either. Any ideas`?

Comment: We need your code to know if it's a coding error.

Comment: Usually, you set up port forwarding in the VM.... I don't believe your question is currently answerable.

Comment: Run ifconfig on the Linux VM and see what IP addresses your Linux VM has.  Then see if you can ping any of those IP addresses from your Windows host.  If so, one of those IP addresses is the one your Windows host can use to connect to the Linux VM.

Comment: Are you using vmware workstation or hyper-v?

Comment: First make sure your VM has connected to the network,whether by NAT or Bridge.Then check your windows ip, ping it on your linux, if it pass, you can use it.

Comment: Sorry for the unsufficient information I provided, please do see my edited question! Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I made a socket-connection using the "
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection, link-to-link IPv6". After reading up on NAT I guess this makes sense!